# verify integer value in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my application, I am taking a value for username.  If that value is 0, then I have to run some code.  But how should I write the if block?

```
 var userName=document.getElementById("member").value;
```

The above statement will return 0 (zero).  Can anybody write the if statement for me?  Thank you in advance.This is the entire code

```
var userName=document.getElementById("member").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(userName==="0"){
        var div4 = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
        var text1 = "insert userName.";
        div4.style.display = "block";
        div4.style.color = "red";
        div4.style.fontSize = "65%";
        div4.innerHTML = text1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional to the other answers: you could check for the value 0 this way

```
if (Number(userName) === 0)
```

With the advantage that if the user fills the username field with whitespace only (spaces, tabs etc) it will still evaluate to `true` (that's because the Number conversion trims the parameter value).

Answer (score 0):

As the value of `userName` is of type string, you could use:

```
if (userName === "0") {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.value` attribute will return a string.

In this case, you can compare the value of `userName` to `0`, the string:

```
if (userName == '0') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes I am aware about this, and this should work for sure.but unexpectedly its not working.I have edited the question a bit.Look if you can find out any mistakes.

Comment: What's the error? The code you posted seems fine. Post the HTML as well.

Comment: Well it is working now, but for this if(userName=="0"). Intially it wasnt working maybe because I hadnt cleared cache.